# How to keep the objects generated in recent 5 minutes using redis?

Tags: redis

I don't want to use `keys *` command because it is `O(N)`.

Is it possible to keep the newest Objects in redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using `KEYS` is definitely the way to go. Use a Sorted Set to store key names when you create them and set the score to the time of creation. You can the fetch key names by their creation time with `ZRANGEBYSCORE` and don't forget trimming the older keys from it using `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE`.